# Ubuntu Dual-Boot Issue with Windows 10: Partition List Empty

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, usb-installation, ahci

When trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on my PC (Windows already installed), the partition list during the Ubuntu install is empty. I'm installing from a bootable USB created using Rufus, and I've already created a partition on my hard drive to install Linux on, but the list to select from during Linux install is completely empty. I've tried a fix online that involved switching to AHCI, but that caused my computer to be unable to boot into anything, even using the safemode method. I had to go back into the BIOS and switch back to RAID to get Windows to boot again. I'm not terribly familiar with all of this, so I could be making a simple error that causes one of the issues I'm facing, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to see:  https://superuser.com/questions/1280141/switch-raid-to-ahci-without-reinstalling-windows-10

Comment: You also need Windows fast startup off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation If Windows 10 is UEFI, then be sure to install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. How you boot install media, is how it installs. And some tools like Rufus may make installer either UEFI/gpt or CSM(BIOS)/MBR.https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Shows Windows screens
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: You did not mention `RST` (the 'opposite' of `AHCI`). Is your computer using RST Raid? Then you may find answers [here](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347).